# Children's fantasy/magical realism short story collection from the late 80s/early 90s

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

There's a short story collection I remember having when I was a young kid, some time in the late 80s or early 90s, but I haven't had any luck tracking it down since. I've got no clue about the author or authors, but I'm sure it was a pretty bulky collection with a bright yellow cover, and there's a couple of stories I still remember in at least moderate detail.

- One of the stories was about a kid stuck with family in the middle of nowhere. He'd been given a blue handkerchief by (I think) his grandmother? He was upset about not getting to go into town because it was an overcast day and a storm was coming. They said they'd go into town if the clouds broke, so while he was out on his own in the yard he held the handkerchief up to the sky, and a patch the size of the handkerchief suddenly appeared and surprised him.
- Another one was about a prankster kid in class with a substitute teacher. Either he had magical gear he was using to prank the teacher or the teacher one-upped the kid with magical gear, but I specifically remember there being chalk that sent off multicolored sparks when the teacher wrote on the board.

Those are the two that stuck with me the most, but I'll keep thinking if any other details come to mind.